# Storing large amount of data in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to store a large number of key-value pairs in Google Apps Script,which can be later accessed by the script later on.The problem is I have it on a text file(in a Javascript Array format).

```
words[1]=new Array("String","String");
```

I have 975 such words.

Any Ideas how to proceed? I wold be grateful if relevant code(if any) is provided.

Comment: did you mean 'words[1]' is the first element of an array and the 2 strings are 'key' and 'value' ? and you have 975 such array elements/pairs ?

Comment: That is correct.I have 975 such pairs.

Comment: It is unclear wether you have different values and/or different keys... could you give a more 'real life' example of a couple of data samples ?

Comment: The thing is I have a lot of arrays.Like,

word[1] = new Array("word1","defnition1");
word[2] = new Array("word2","definitin2");
..
word[975] = new Array("word975","definition975");

Now I am kind of looking for some code to store it as a key-value system in scriptDB.

Answer (score 0):

Build your array then use setValues()

```
  var cronicaArr = new Array();

      for (i in data) 
      {

        cronicaArr.push(["string1", "string2"]);         

      }
  myActiveSheet.getRange("A2:A"+cronicaArr.length).setValues(cronicaArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GAS documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) has an entire section dedicated to data storage where your question  as well as many more will be answered. Please read through the 'Storing Data' section.

To answer your question specifically, you can use any of ScriptProperties, ScriptDB or a spreadsheet to store your data.

Comment: The link does not bring to "Storing Data" section. Perhaps the section is removed?

Answer (score -1):

Miturbe's answer only achieves saving the data. I assume you also want to query it (get value from key).
For that store it on scriptdb. Beware of size limits (which deppend on what type of google account the script runs on), then backup the db on a sheet regularly.